# equals() is not working

Tags: java, android, string, equals

```
package com.example.life.bluebell;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
   }
   EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
   String et = edittext.getText().toString();
   if(et.equals("ab123"))
   {
       System.out.println("asdfg");
   }
}
```

i am getting error at

```
if(et.equals("ab123"))
```

'equals' is shown as error with cannot resolve symbol type
i have tried comparing some other predeclared string instead of 'et' but still it is generating same error

Comment: What's the value of `edittext` and `et`?

Comment: remove `}`, which is after `setContentView(..)` and add it at last line..

Comment: why are trying to compare the string in Oncreate? in onCreate the `Editext` is empty. so it gives `Trying to access null object`

Comment: You need your comparison code to be inside the onCreate() method. doing things outside the method is what is causing the issue.

Comment: Used the et .equalsIgnoreCase() for string and format your code put in oncreate not outside....

Answer (score 0):

Write the following inside your `OnCreate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String et = edittext.getText().toString();
    if(et.equals("sss"))
    {
        System.out.println("asdfg");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , I am sure this will work

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override  

   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
     EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
     String et = edittext.getText().toString();
     if(et.equals("ab123")) {
       System.out.println("asdfg");
     }
   }   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the comparison code inside the method scope of onCreate(). In java, it is not allowed to do operations outside a method or an instance block or a static block inside a class.

Modify your own code like:

```
package com.example.life.bluebell;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

      EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
      String et = edittext.getText().toString();
      if(et.equals("ab123"))
      {
          Log.d("Myactivity","asdfg");
          //system out will not be of much use and will only print on console. Use log instead to see output in Logcat
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put this code in some method like

```
public void getData(){
EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
   String et = edittext.getText().toString();
   if(et.equals("ab123"))
   {
       System.out.println("asdfg");
   }
}
```

and dont call this `getData()` in `onCreate()`,
call it in some `Button` click action like follows

```
cButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {              
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getData();
            }
        });
```

your complete code would be like

```
public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

      Button cButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.custom_button);
      cButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getData();
            }
        });
   }
   public void getData() {
       EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
       String et = edittext.getText().toString();
       if(et.equals("ab123")) {
           System.out.println("asdfg");
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First u have to check the reference editText is correct or not, then after just follow the below codes,

```
    public class login extends AppCompatActivity {
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

          checkValue();

       }

    public void checkValue()
    {
       EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
       String et = edittext.getText().toString().trim();
       if(et.contentEquals("ab123")) // if(et.equalsIgnoreCase("ab123"))
       {
           System.out.println("asdfg");
       }
    }
    }

    It will help u.
```